# How do I keep a nav menu bar item in the active state after it's been pressed and flipped to the page it should be on

Tags: css

So, what I would like to happen is that once the menu item is pressed, the site flips to that page but the button that leads to that page remains in the active state while on that page to show the user where they are on the site. So far, I haven't found a combination that works and I would like this to work purely with css3.

**html**

```
<div id="navMenu">
                <ul id="MenuBar1" class="MenuBarHorizontal">
                    <li><a href="index.html">&nbsp;HOME&nbsp;</a></li>
                    <li><a href="surveying.html">SURVEYING</a></li>
                    <li><a href="engineering.html">ENGINEERING</a></li>
                    <li><a href="companyProfile.html">COMPANY PROFILE</a></li>
                    <li><a href="products.html">PRODUCTS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="clients.html">CLIENTS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contacUs.html">CONTACT US&nbsp;</a></li>
                </ul>
        </div>
```

**css3**

```
#navMenu {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 5% 0 0 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#navMenuActive {
    position: absolute;
    height: 47px;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: red;
}
#navMenuActiveText {
    margin: 16px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
}
ul.MenuBarHorizontal {
    width: 100%;
    alignment-baseline: central;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: default;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
ul.MenuBarHorizontal li {
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 18px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul.MenuBarHorizontal a:link, ul.MenuBarHorizontal a:visited {
    padding:17px 23px 8px 23px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: -.5px;
    margin-right: -.5px;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    color: #555;
    background-image: url(../images/navBar_i.png);
}
ul.MenuBarHorizontal a, ul.MenuBarHorizontal a:hover, ul.MenuBarHorizontal a:active {
    color: rgb(255,255,255);
    background-image: url(../images/navBar_a.png);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the target page, place a classname like "current" on the item that indicates the page the user is on,

```
            <ul id="MenuBar1" class="MenuBarHorizontal">
                <li><a href="index.html">&nbsp;HOME&nbsp;</a></li>
                <li><a href="surveying.html">SURVEYING</a></li>
                <li class="current"><a href="engineering.html">ENGINEERING</a></li>
                <li><a href="companyProfile.html">COMPANY PROFILE</a></li>
                <li><a href="products.html">PRODUCTS</a></li>
                <li><a href="clients.html">CLIENTS</a></li>
                <li><a href="contacUs.html">CONTACT US&nbsp;</a></li>
           </ul>
```

and style appropriately.

```
   .current{font-weight:bold /* etc. */ }
```